# How to prevent `git checkout` from checking out specific file types?

Tags: git, gitignore, ignore, msysgit, git-checkout

We are creating a system in which users will be able to push arbitrary content to a shared Git repository. Our server will then checkout the repository and use the files.

To reduce risks, I'd like the `git checkout` command not to write any `.exe`, `.cmd`, `.bat` etc. on disk, and control which file types will be written.

How to configure Git (either using a configuration file, or a command-line argument) to ignore/skip specific file types at checkout?

Note that I'm running Git for Windows.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that comes to my mind is to use a smudge filter that you can specify as part of your `gitattributes` file ([Customizing Git - Git Attributes](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes)).

Or, if you want to prevent these files from being committed in the first place, maybe placing a `pre-recieve` hook ([Git hooks](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks)) on your git server might be the way to go.

Comment: `smudge` sounds like a good solution, even though it would, as far as I understand, "empty" the file instead of just skipping it, and it would also require running an executable for each file. The `pre-receive` hook also sounds like a good idea, I'll have to check how  that can be configured. If no better answer is suggested, that's gonna be it :) It doesn't look simple though: https://github.com/avar/pre-receive-reject-binaries/blob/master/pre-receive-reject-binaries

Comment: @ChristianRondeau did you ever figure out a better solution for this issue? What did you end up doing? I have the same problem.

Comment: We actually never "solved" this. We still rely on manual and security checks before and at deployment time, rather than prevent these files from being checked in. In our case, this is still manageable, though I'd much prefer to have something built-in. We'll revisit this sometime in the future, so if you do find a good solution, please share it :)